# Center current line to the center of screen when opening a file

Tags: vimrc

I would like to execute 'zz' to center the current line to the center of the screen when opening a new file.  I have tried the following, but it does not seem to be working for some reason:

```
autocmd BufEnter * :normal zz
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Leaving aside that you should use `augroup`, `BufReadPost` and `normal!`, it actually does work. But `zz` is no-op if the current line number is too small.

Comment: Repeating what Matt said but in different terms (which may or may not help): `zz` will not do anything if centering the current line would result in a margin (empty space) at the top of the buffer.